# How do I get a sensors output in conky?

Tags: conky, sensors

I am trying to use conky to display my sensors output but have no idea where to start. I've seen other scripts and they dont make any seance to me. I've tried a few scripts here and there but none seem to work with mine.

My Sensors output is as follows.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +48.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 0:         +49.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:         +44.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
```

The conky im using is as follows:

```
TEXT
${color #42AE4A}Processes:${color lightgrey} $processes ${color #42AE4A}Run:${color lightgrey} $running_processes ${color #42AE4A}
${color #42AE4A}Core 1 Temp: ${color lightgrey}${exec sensors | grep 'Core0'} ${color #42AE4A}Core 2 Temp: ${color lightgrey}${exec sensors | grep 'Core1'}
```

The ui output is seen here

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JUrj7qu.jpg]

I don't know much about conky scripting, anything helps. And please don't just suggest trying scripts until one works. I rather learn what i'm doing then copy a script. Having said that, the above script is actually copyed and I have no idea what exec means or does, but I assume it stands for execute.

EDIT: Changed the last two lines in conky to:

```
${color #42AE4A}Core 0 Temp: ${color lightgrey}${exec sensors | grep 'Core 0'}
${color #42AE4A}Core 1 Temp: ${color lightgrey}${exec sensors | grep 'Core 1'}
```

Now the output is as follows:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/KcKglE9.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it. I learned of the cut command. The last two lines now look like this.

```
${color #42AE4A}Core 0 Temp: ${color lightgrey}${exec sensors | grep 'Core 0' | cut -c18-21}
${color #42AE4A}Core 1 Temp: ${color lightgrey}${exec sensors | grep 'Core 1' | cut -c18-21}
```